# jQuery remove current active class on each trigger

Tags: jquery

I have wrote a jQuery function which reads the selected option value from a select box and adds an active class to the div which is corresponding with that value.

```
jQuery(".product-customize select").on("change", function() {
    var activeLocation = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /, '');
    var dot = '.';
    var activeLocationDiv = jQuery('.locations').find(dot + activeLocation);
    activeLocationDiv.addClass('active');
});
```

This is working but I try to achieve that every time that the select box is triggered, the current active class would be removed so that you always have only one active div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(".product-customize select").on("change", function() {
$('.active').removeClass('active');//remove class active from all elements
var activeLocation = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /, '');
var dot = '.';
var activeLocationDiv = jQuery('.locations').find(dot + activeLocation);
activeLocationDiv.addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue chaining your code like this to remove class `active` from other `option` siblings:

```
activeLocationDiv.addClass('active').find('option:selected').siglings('option').removeClass('active');
```

Final code look like:

```
jQuery(".product-customize select").on("change", function() {
    var activeLocation = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /, '');
    var dot = '.';
    var activeLocationDiv = jQuery('.locations').find(dot + activeLocation);
       activeLocationDiv.addClass('active').find('option:selected').siglings('option').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is solved here
   use .removeclass(''); before the trigger.. Shown below

```
  jQuery(".product-customize select").on("change", function() {

   var activeLocation = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /, '');
   var dot = '.';
  var activeLocationDiv = jQuery('.locations').find(dot + activeLocation);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');// Place it here
  activeLocationDiv.addClass('active');
  });
```